# jquery click and hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am writing a program and when you click a div it is suppose to hide it's own class, and display another class but it does not work, here is my code.

```
$("#one").click(function(){

  var c = name1.length;
  if (c % 2 > 0) {
    j = 1;
    $(".color").hide();
    $(".text3").show();

  }else if(c % 2 == 0){
     j = 0;
     $(".color").hide();
     $(".text2").show();
  }


});
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `name1`? How does your HTML look?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#one").click(function() {   
    $( this ).toggleClass( "your_class" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the code looks correct. Without seeing it in the context of the website I'd think your issue could be one of the following:

- jQuery is not correctly attached to the page
- The variable `j` isn't in scope
- One of your IDs cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

Try to put inside document.ready, without it your script won't run.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#one" ).on( "click", function() {

     var c = name1.length;
     if (c % 2 > 0) {
      j = 1;
      $(".color").hide();
      $(".text3").show();

     }else if(c % 2 == 0){
      j = 0;
      $(".color").hide();
      $(".text2").show();
     }
  });  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't want to show/hide a different diff with that class names, but instead you want to toggle the class names of div#one.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I am trying to hide #one and show some other text after.